# webpack angular project in production

Tags: angularjs, caching, webpack, production

Im an using webpack angular project and have successfully able to generate the bundle and inject it into the index.html file.

But in browser i can see the addition Webpack FOLDER in the source tab that has old code unless i clear the browser cache i cannot find the latest code.   However there are generated bundles and styles but my pages dont take these files, they are taking code from the webpack folder.

Im attaching the folder structure that i see in the browser, U can see the build folder from where the code is rendered and also the webpack folder where the latest code is not updating , any help appreciated, 
Thanks 
[image]

====================================================
Webpack.development.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require("path");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const nodeModulesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname,'app/build');
const mainPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app', 'index.js');
const config = {
    context:__dirname, 
    entry:  {
     app:[
        mainPath
      ],
    vendors: ['jquery','angular']
    },
    output:{
        path:buildPath,
        filename:"bundle.min.js",
        publicPath: "http://website.oo.com/build/" // development
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve:{
        alias:{     
            jquery: "jquery/src/jquery"
        },
        extensions:['','.js','.css','.less','.html']
    },
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {test: /\.js$/,loader: 'babel-loader',query:{presets: ["es2015"],compact: false},exclude: '/node_modules/'},  
            {test: /\.less$/,loader:ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css','less']) },   
            {test: /\.css$/,loader:ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css'])},  
            {test: /\.html$/,loader: "html?config=otherHtmlLoaderConfig"},
            {test: /bootstrap\/js\//, loader:'imports?jQuery=jquery'}, 
            {test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader:'url-loader',query:{limit:100000}},
            {test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff"},
            {test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" },
            {test: /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]some-module[\/\\]index\.js$/,loader: "imports?this=>window"}   
        ]
  }, 
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({$: "jquery",jQuery: "jquery"}),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin({minSizeReduce:1,moveToParents: true}),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({compress: { warnings: false },comments:false,sourceMap:true,minimize: true}),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.min.css', { allChunks: true }),  
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors', 'vendor.min.js'),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['app/build'],{verbose: true,dry: false,exclude: ['vendor.min.js'],watch:false}),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Onepoint Global Account',
      template:path.join(__dirname,'app','index.html'),
      inject: 'body'}),
  ]
};
module.exports = config;
```

========================================================
Package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "local": "webpack-dev-server --content-base app",
    "server": "node server",
    "build": "set NODE_ENV=production && webpack -d --watch -p --config  webpack.development.config.js"
  }
```

I use the command   "npm run build" to start the project.

Comment: If this is folder structure you see when running webpack dev serevr - it is OK. This is what you want to see - webpack show you result bundles (build/..) as well as your source code (webpack://..) so you can easily debug you application. Please explain more detailed what you are unhappy with. Giving your webpack config and command you run your app will also help.

Comment: there are 2 things im unhappy about. 1. is URL i have  to add  "build" 
 -  "www.website.com/build/#/login"   to render the updated files.                2. And even after that , Webpack Folder that u see in the image, source code does not have the latest html or js changes (unless i clear browser cache - ctrl+shift +delete)

Comment: I am using webpack in production mode and not webpack-dev-server. 
@PetrAveryanov have updated my question with the config file and the command im using to run the project.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Any help in this regard, much appreciated ?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To address your two points:

1. `/build` is in the URL because of this line:

   ```
   publicPath: "http://website.oo.com/build/" // development
   ```

   Your `buildPath` is the directory you can host your site from.
2. Do you have a `webpack.prod.config.js`? It's OK to only have one webpack config file, but please be aware that you are running production (`set NODE_ENV=production`, and `-p`) with your development config. If you want to defeat the browser caching, you can specify a hash in your output file:

   ```
   output: {
     ...
     filename:"bundle.[hash].min.js",
   },
   ```